# Partial string match in join using ilike in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, wildcard

I have two tables in postgres which I am joining to extract substrings.

```
tb1

id              drug1
NCT01805934 veramyst
(few more rows follows)
```

```
tb2
id    drug2
1 fluticasone furoate (veramyst®) nasal spray
(few more rows follows)
```

I am using below query to perform substring match.

```
select * from tb1
left join
tb2 on (tb1.drug1 ilike '%' || tb2.drug2 || '%') or (tb2.drug2 ilike '%' || tb1.drug1  || '%')
```

However I am getting all matches instead of full string match. I am expecting only last row as my output

```
output
NCT01805934 ra  veramyst
NCT03252574 a   veramyst
NCT00728715 a   veramyst
NCT01525511 a   veramyst
NCT03793985 t   veramyst
NCT04215003 a   veramyst
NCT03793985 r   veramyst
NCT01279057 fluticasone furoate (veramyst®) nasal spray veramyst
```

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Please format your example tables correctly, so we know where the columns begin and end.  And include headers in your output table.

Comment: The extra rows in output are generated by input rows you have not show us.  It looks like the answer is not to do the ilike comparison in both directions, but only in the direction which produces the answer you want.